# Is there a viable open source antivirus for OS/X?

Tags: antivirus, macos

I am interested in finding an antivirus program for the Mac, but not one from Symantec, because I don't trust them.

I wonder if perhaps there is an open source solution for antivirus for OS/X?

Or how about just an open source program that can monitor the system looking for suspicious behavior, like outgoing connections to servers in Romania or China?

Comment: Just curious, why don't you trust Symantec? (I have no affiliation with them...)

Answer (score 7):

This is really two questions and aren't really handled well by a single program.

The antivirus question is easy, you'll be wanting [ClamX](http://www.clamxav.com/). It is an OSX port of the venerable ClamAV engine. It is widely considered to be the default AV for Unix/Linux systems.

For your other question, free utilities that have good Mac integration may be hard to come across. The best tool I can think of would be a software firewall called [Little Snitch](http://www.obdev.at/products/littlesnitch/index.html). Since you can have it ask you to approve connections, as well as define what applications are allowed to talk to where, you *might* be able to accomplish what you need.

Now, with all that, keep in mind that if your computer is already infected, you can't trust the output of either of these applications. Clever viruses will just bypass the applications and continue working anyway. Applications like this are really useful for preventing yourself *from* being compromised, or detecting lame infections.